# VSI CURL hits SSL error

Tags: gdal, planet

I tried to play with the tutorial from *Planet.com* but it looks like I cannot assign the download link (active) to `vsicurl` driver, as the tutorial said. I tried the `gdalinfo` and get the error related to SSL cert. Has anyone solved this issue?

```
C:\Users\lan>gdalinfo /vsicurl/https://api.planet.com/data/v1/download?token=eyJ
hbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhQlQ1dmY1clo0Q1M3RFlKY0FYd1ZyUEJUUX
lTT2hHaTVrc3dYREN5Y3dEUUpUS1VzY2FJczI5Mjkya1NsajQzd0JlSDlGeXNLZXlFaWcyRFlpbHBEdz
09IiwiaXRlbV90eXBlX2lkIjoiUFNTY2VuZTRCYW5kIiwidG9rZW5fdHlwZSI6InR5cGVkLWl0ZW0iLC
JleHAiOjE1Mzk5MjY0MzksIml0ZW1faWQiOiIyMDE4MTAxNl8yMTQ1NDNfMTAyZSIsImFzc2V0X3R5cG
UiOiJhbmFseXRpYyJ9.BiqYstlQkh3jKUIKkAPozMn7MYqUIuO_CoBEmuKLrAZNuBQZKHNZIiskhP-ha
1kedzYRKrywwr-UR16BW68gUw
ERROR 11: CURL error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certif
icate
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/vsicurl/https://api.planet.com/data/v1/downlo
ad?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhQlQ1dmY1clo0Q1M3RFlKY0
FYd1ZyUEJUUXlTT2hHaTVrc3dYREN5Y3dEUUpUS1VzY2FJczI5Mjkya1NsajQzd0JlSDlGeXNLZXlFaW
cyRFlpbHBEdz09IiwiaXRlbV90eXBlX2lkIjoiUFNTY2VuZTRCYW5kIiwidG9rZW5fdHlwZSI6InR5cG
VkLWl0ZW0iLCJleHAiOjE1Mzk5MjY0MzksIml0ZW1faWQiOiIyMDE4MTAxNl8yMTQ1NDNfMTAyZSIsIm
Fzc2V0X3R5cGUiOiJhbmFseXRpYyJ9.BiqYstlQkh3jKUIKkAPozMn7MYqUIuO_CoBEmuKLrAZNuBQZK
HNZIiskhP-ha1kedzYRKrywwr-UR16BW68gUw'.
```

Comment: What version of GDAL? VSICURL is working for me as expected with Planet data.

Comment: Hi there, I have gdal 1500 + python biding for Python 2.7.15 32 bit. Everything is fine, just the vsicurl does not work. Do you have any idea? I may try to turn off the verification as below suggestion. Thanks

Comment: 1500 isn't a GDAL version number. It'll be 1.x or 2.x.

Comment: Oh sorry I have version 2.2.3 released in 2017/11/20  and python 2.7.15  32bit on a Win7 pro testing machine :). Turning on the GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL did the work. I know can clip directly from the VSICURL. Thank you very much!

Comment: That looks right but it wouldn't hurt to try a more recent version to see if it helps. In general disabling a HTTPS check is a bad thing to do but I realise it will unblock your current problem.

Comment: Could you please explain how bad is the "bad thing" ? if we need a cert to keep the HTTPS check alive? it is a bit urgent for me to get the job done but of course we want to do thing in proper way.

Comment: It's p potentially a symptom of a larger security issue on your system. It's unlikely but you could be subject to a man-in-the-middle attack. Generally you don't want to ignore a HTTPS error without knowing why you are seeing it.

Answer (score 4):

It should be able to make GDAL to skip the certificate check with a configuration option: [HTTP_UNSAFESSL](http://[https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL][1])

Have a try by adding this into your `gdalinfo` command:

`--config GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL YES`

Comment: Thank you! You did answer my question. Turning on the UNSAFESSL is what I'm after. Best regards, Alan

Comment: @user111189, if this answer solved your question you should accept it (and probably upvote it as well). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Tks.